# Call variables from Name Manager in VBA Editor window

Tags: excel, vba

I want to manipulate the data from variables defined in Name Manager.

I'll refer to the first image at this URL. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-name-manager-in-excel-4d8c4c2b-9f7d-44e3-a3b4-9f61bd5c64e4

I can see the Name of the Variables when I try the following code:

```
  For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names

       Debug.Print n.Name

  Next n
```

In the 'Immediate' window I would see (per image in URL)

```
  Amount
  Extract
  Profit
  Quantity
  Table5
```

If I delete the .Name after Debug.Print n, then I get the ranges in the 'Refers To' column

I want to be able to be able to call the variable and be able to use the data.

For Example something like:

```
  For i=0 to length(Amount)
     Debug.Print Amount(i)
  Next i
```

or

```
  Debug.Print Table5(2,3)
```

or with a hypothetical 5x10 array

```
  For i=0 to length(array(1,:)) 'whole column of array. might be matlab code. oops
       if array(1,i) = 52
             a.add = array(1,i)  'syntax might be screwy, but add to list
       end if
  next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
Dim cel As Range

For Each cel In Range(Amount)
    Debug.Print cel.Value
Next
```

Those are `Named Ranges`, and you can access than using `Range` Object. Then `loop` over the `Range` to get the Individual `Cell Value`